# CosmosDB Deserialize String As List

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I need to change an existing model property type from `string` to `List<string>`.

Because my database already has several instances of such model with the string property, I'd like to find a way to read the property:

- If it is valorized as string, return a new List with the item
- If it's valorized as a List, return as is

I am on .NET Core 6 and I believe my two options are

1. Add a decorator to the property
2. Modify the SQL query and try to parse string as array

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you clarify which language you are using and what things have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On .NET you can define a method that handles custom deserialization/serialization.

The V3 SDK uses Newtonsoft, so I'll use that as an example, you can implement `JsonConverter` (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<string>);
    }

    // Used for serializing, if true, override WriteJson
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; }}

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        JToken itemsJToken = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (itemsJToken.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            return new List<string>(){ itemsJToken.Value<string>() };
        }
        else // assuming it can only be an array
        {
            return itemsJToken.ToObject<List<string>>(serializer);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    /* other properties */
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
    public List<string> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! That's exactly what I was looking for